# SSH access to VM instances

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

1. Does GCP restrict user/pwd based access to its VM instances remotely? When I try to access the host from another instance (ssh user@host) it says can't connect missing public key.
2. if ssh key is the only method supported on gcp, is it advisable to set (re-set) password for default users (root & gmailuser) and user defined account(s)?
3. when I click on SSH within console window, it directly connects me to terminal using the default google user account. How do I set the firewall rules to restrict other ways of SSH access so that only the logged in user (myself) will be able to ssh directly from console. Default f/w rule is open for 0.0.0.0/0 incoming IP adresses.
4. where is the ssh key stored for the default google user that can take me to the VM instance? And whats the source IP of the console? If I know this, I can think of a way to restrict/define the f/w rule for qn 3.

Thanks. I am in the process of learning these. if anything is not clear, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

> Does GCP restrict user/pwd based access to its VM instances remotely?
>   When I try to access the host from another instance (ssh user@host) it
>   says can't connect missing public key.

In GCP by default, for [public images](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images#os-details) and most common operating systems root login and password authentication is disabled. Though you can connect as root using SSH if you configure them accordingly see [this](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced#root)

> when I click on SSH within console window, it directly connects me to
>   terminal using the default google user account. How do I set the
>   firewall rules to restrict other ways of SSH access so that only the
>   logged in user (myself) will be able to ssh directly from console.
>   Default f/w rule is open for 0.0.0.0/0 incoming IP adresses.

For access restriction GCP uses IAM. To restrict ssh access see [this](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/#granting_users_ssh_access_to_vm_instances)

> where is the ssh key stored for the default google user that can take
>   me to the VM instance? And whats the source IP of the console? If I
>   know this, I can think of a way to restrict/define the f/w rule for qn
>   3

See [Where SSH keys are located](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance#where_ssh_keys_are_located)

Comment: Thanks John. I will got through these links.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution ?